# factor $y'$ as $y' = f(x)g(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, factoring

I have a task where I have to write following differential equation as $y' = f(x)g(y)$ but I see no way you could factor it into two functions each only depending on $x$ respectively $y$:

$$y' = \exp\left[-x \cos(x) + \sin(x)+ 4x\right] + x\sin(x)y$$

Do you know a way of factoring this or can you confirm that you cannot factor this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint(This may be considered cheating); You can solve for $y(x)$ with the D.E given, differentiate the solution, name the result of differentiation $f(x)$ and let $g(y)=1$.

Comment: That would be a solution but I do not think that this is the point of the whole task=) (But I am not sure whether this would solve it since ther obviously IS a $y$ in the term so $g(y) \neq 1$.)